# How does Perl regexp anchor $ actually handle a trailing newline?

Tags: regex, perl, end-of-line

I recently discovered some unexpected behaviour for the end-of-string anchor `$` in a Perl Regular Expression (Perl 5.26.1 x86_64 on OpenSuse 15.2).

Supposedly, the `$` refers to the end of the *string*, not the end of a *line* as it does in grep(1).  Hence an explicit `\n` at the end of a string should have to be matched explicitly.  However, the following (complete) program:

```
my @strings = ( 
  "hello world",
  "hello world\n",
  "hello world\t"
);
my $i = 0;
foreach (@strings) {
  $i++;
  print "$i: >>$_<<\n" if /d$/;
}
```

produces this output:

```
1: >>hello world<<
2: >>hello world
<<
```

i.e., the `/d$/` matches not only the first of the three strings but also the second with its trailing newline.  On the other hand, as expected, the regexp `/d\n$/` matches the second string only, and `/d\s$/` matches the second and third.

What's going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[perlre](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre#Metacharacters) states for the `$` metacharacter:

> Match the end of the string
> (or before newline at the end of the string;

This means that `d` followed immediately by `\n` (newline) will match the regex.

Answer (score 3):

As stated already, the [$ metacharacter](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre#Metacharacters) indeed matches the end of *string*, but allowing for a newline so matching before a newline at the end of string as well.  Note that it also matches before internal newlines in a multiline string with the `/m` [global modifier](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre#Modifiers)

There are also ways to fine tune what exactly is matched, using [these assertions](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre#Assertions)

- `\z` match only the end of string, even with `/m` flag, but *not* before the newline at the end
- `\Z` match only the end of string, even with `/m` flag, and also match before the newline at the end of string. So like `$` except that it never matches (before) newlines internal to a multi-line string, not even with `/m`

These "zero-width" assertions match a position, not characters.